# Dynamic resource loader

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it possible, to make this:
1. Index.html have  Http get, what fetches json string with needed artifacts (js, html,css, etc)
2. We have a some "starting point" in our app what will be use this preloaded artifacts.

What libs, tech we could use for this usecase?

Comment: Do you mean like loading css, html and js automatically from different location?

Comment: `requirejs` also does the same.